Does an Ally Across Time benefit from passive effects from gear?
Ally Across Time states:

Although the duplicate appears with all of the equipment you currently
carry, it cannot use any of its equipment and all its equipment
disappears when the duplicate does.

Does this mean they can still benefit from passive effects of equipment, such as Benevolent weapons and armor, or Menacing weapons?
Would their Necklace of Adaptation protect them?
Can their Necklace of Fireballs be detonated?
Or would any or all of this fall under the category of "using their equipment"?
